# Problems rendering to my twig template

Tags: php, symfony, templates, twig

When I render to my twig template file it cannot find the template in the templates directory.

The code is as follows:

```
    public function show($slug)
    {
        return $this->render("home/index.html.twig");
    }
```

The templates directory is as follows:

> templates/home/index.html.twig

Having tested with it, clearing did not effect the problem. It also did not recognise the base.html.twig file.

Any help with any solutions to allow me to render to my twig templates would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you check the twig path on config.yml?